# A equence $(a_n)$ such that $(a_{2k})$, $(a_{2k+1})$ and $(a_{3k})$ are all convergent subsequences is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\{a_{2k}\}$, $\{a_{2k+1}\}$ and $\{a_{3k}\}$ are all convergent subsequences. Show that $\{a_n\}$ is also convergent.

My idea is that I must show that $\{a_{2k}\}$, $\{a_{2k+1}\}$ and $\{a_{3k}\}$ all converge to the same limit and then using this fact show $\{a_n\}$ also converges to that limit.

But I dont know how to show $\{a_{2k}\}$, $\{a_{2k+1}\}$ and $\{a_{3k}\}$ all converge to the same limit.

Any help will be grateful :D

Comment: I was thinking maybe the shift rule could be applied to show lim(a2k) = lim(a2k+k)?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at the sequences $a_{6k}$ and $a_{6k+3}$.

You should be able to see $a_{6k}$ is a subsequence of both $a_{2k}$ and $a_{3k}$ and similarly $a_{6k+3}$ is a subsequence of $a_{3k}$ and $a_{2k+1}$ because $6k{+}3$ is an odd number divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** considering the subsequence $(a_{6k})$ we can show that the subsequences $(a_{2k})$ and $(a_{3k})$ have the same limit. Consider $(a_{3(2k+1)})$ to conclude.